# Need Help on Scoring Mechanism

Tags: vb.net

So i have created a simple scoring mechanism, where the program compares words in two list boxes and allocates points depending on accurancy.

Points are allocated as follows:

- 2 points for correct answer (the righ word with captial letter)
- 1 point for partially correct answer (the right word without capital letter)
- 0 points when incorrect

The scoring mechanism works correctly if the words match, but when someone types completely different from the correct word it still allocates him 2 points if it has capital letter, and 1 point if it has not have capital letter.

I lack a piece of code which would tell the program that if the word is a complete mis-match with the correct answer, that 0 points are allocated.

Here is my piece of code, could you tell what i need to add?

```
Dim UserScore As Integer = 0 

For Counter As Integer = 0 To lstStudentAnswers.Items.Count - 1
    If UCase(lstStudentAnswers.Items(Counter).ToString) = UCase(lstProgramAnswers.Items(Counter).ToString) Then
        UserScore = UserScore + 1

        If Char.IsUpper(lstStudentAnswers.Items(Counter).ToString, 0) Then
            UserScore = UserScore + 1
        End If
    End If

    txtTotalScore.Text = UserScore
Next
```

Comment: So basically (UCase("Word1") = UCase("NotWord1")) equates to true in your case? Have you set a breakpoint on the first If line and looked at the values for the list items that are compared?

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following... (assuming that the Program Answers have correct case).

```
Dim UserScore As Integer = 0 


For Counter As Integer = 0 To lstStudentAnswers.Items.Count - 1



    If UCase(lstStudentAnswers.Items(Counter).ToString) = UCase(lstProgramAnswers.Items(Counter).ToString) Then
        'User answer and Program answer are the same case insensitive.
        UserScore = UserScore + 1

        If lstStudentAnswers.Items(Counter).ToString = lstProgramAnswers.Items(Counter).ToString Then
            'Additional point for getting case right
            UserScore = UserScore + 1

        End If

    End If
    txtTotalScore.Text = UserScore
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function to compare two words:

```
Private Function CompareWords(ByVal submittedWord As String, ByVal expectedWord As String) As Integer

    Dim result As Integer = 0

    If submittedWord.ToLower() <> expectedWord.ToLower() Then
        ' Submitted word is not the same as expected word
        Return result
    End If

    ' Words are the same, but need to check case of each character
    result += 1

    For letterIndex As Integer = 0 To submittedWord.Length - 1
        If submittedWord(letterIndex) <> expectedWord(letterIndex) Then
            ' Case of submitted word is not the same as the expected word
            Return result
        End If
    Next
    result += 1

    Return result

End Function
```

This way you only need to provide the student answer and the program answer to get the resultant score, by iterating the student answers.